# Oracle best way to pair records

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping, traversal

I have a table called access_history, which keeps track of the location, card number, datetime when an employee presents an access card to a sensor.

Currently, employees are using time cards to punch in and out to record their start and end time in a daily basis. Yes, I know that is very much an antiquated method. That is why I was thrown this project  to capture this data and convert it to a time and attendance system.

I was thinking about using a trigger to accomplish this but I believe there are 2 issues. First, there is already existing data that needs to be converted. Secondly, if the trigger is disabled or deleted I will lose data and become out if sync. So I'm thinking the best way is to crawl through the data and create attendance records.

Being a DBA, and NOT a developer, I was thinking the best way to do this is with a merge statement aka upsert. If the record is there update it else INSERT it. Btw, if this isn't the best method I am open to any and all suggestions including design changes.

Keep in mind I have about 10k employees and about a million+ history records daily that I need to scan through so feel free to add any keys, partutions…

I know there maybe plenty of inserts and updates since I'm updating the emp_info table for each employee. Any thoughts on avoiding that would be great.

Note, there may be more than 1 pair of start and end dates in the emp_attendance table as people may go out for lunch or go to a different building. Secondly, since we are 24x7  the end date can cross midnight. In my sample test case I provide an example of that situation.

I was hoping someone can provide me some code or get me started on how to traverse and pair the data.

I know I would need a query on the emp_histoty table where location_type =T and see if the date >  last/start_date un the employees table

Any and all help us greatly appreciated. The more details and specifics would be great. Thanks to all who answer.

```
-- Drop table emp_info purge:
-- Drop table locations purge;
-- Drop table access_histoty purge;
-- Drop table emp_attendance purge;



CREATE TABLE employees
(
   employee_id NUMBER(6),
   first_name VARCHAR2(20),
   last_name VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
   card_num varchar2(10)  NOT NULL,
   Last_start_date DATE
);

ALTER TABLE employees
     ADD ( CONSTRAINT employee_id_pk
   PRIMARY KEY (employee_id));


Insert into employees values (1, 'Mike', 'Jones', 'AAA1', NULL);

Insert into employees values (2, 'Jane', 'Doe', 'BBB2', NULL);


Insert into employees values (3, 'Paul', 'Smith', 'CCC3', NULL);

Insert into employees values (4, 'John', 'Henry', 'DDD4', NULL);



 Create table locations(
   location_id NUMBER(4),
   location_name varchar2(30),
   location_type char(1));

 -- A=access T=Time & Attendance 

ALTER TABLE locations 
     ADD ( CONSTRAINT lication_id_pk
   PRIMARY KEY (location_id));



Insert into locations values (101, 'South Front Door 1', 'T');

  Insert into locations values (102, 'South Front Door 2', 'T');

  Insert into locations values (103, 'East Back Door 1', 'T');

   Insert into locations values (104, 'East Back Door 2', 'T');

   Insert into locations values (105,'Computer Room', 'A');

   Insert into locations values (106,'1st Floor North',  'A');


Create table access_history(
   employee_id NUMBER(6), 
   card_num varchar2(10),
   location_id number(4),
   Access_date date
);


INSERT INTO access_history
( employee_id, card_num,
   location_id, Access_date )
 VALUES (1, 'AAA1', 101,    TO_DATE('06212020 21:02:04',  'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS'));


   -- TYpe T no previous data for this
   -- empid record INSERT empid, 
    -- start  time ONLY in table below 
     -- and  update last_start_date  
     -- with DATETIME.



INSERT INTO access_history
( employee_id, card_num,
   location_id, Access_date )
 VALUES (1, 'AAA1', 102,    TO_DATE('06212020 23:52:14',  'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS'));


  -- Type T record empid, start_time
  --  set update end_time only in
  -- emp_attendance.



INSERT INTO access_history
( employee_id, card_num,
   location_id, Access_date )
 VALUES (2, 'BBB2', 103,    TO_DATE('06212020 08:32:35',  'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS'));


 -- TYpe T  INSERT empid, start 
 -- time ONLY in emp_attendance.  
 -- update last_start_date with 
 --  DATETIME on emp_info table



INSERT INTO access_history
( employee_id, card_num,
   location_id, Access_date )
 VALUES (2, 'BBB2', 102,    TO_DATE('06212020 15:39:05',  'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS'));


-- Type T record empid, start_time 
--  set, update end_time only in
-- emp_attendance.


INSERT INTO access_history
( employee_id, card_num,
   location_id, Access_date )
 VALUES (3, 'CCC3', 103,    TO_DATE('06212020 15:39:05',  'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS'));


 -- TYpe T  INSERT empid, start 
 -- time ONLY in emp_attendance.  
 -- update last_start_date with 
 --  DATETIME on emp_info table



INSERT INTO access_history
( employee_id, card_num,
   location_id, Access_date )
 VALUES (3, 'CCC3', 105,    TO_DATE('06212020 18:19:55',  'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS'));


-- Type A record don't do anything to 
-- emp_attendance.


INSERT INTO access_history
( employee_id, card_num,
   location_id, Access_date )
 VALUES (3, 'CCC3', 104,    TO_DATE('06222020 04:04:35',  'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS'));


-- Type T record empid, start_time 
--  set, update end_time only in
-- emp_attendance.


-- After the first run the output 
-- should.   look like this:



 CREATE TABLE  emp_attendance    
  (employee_id NUMBER(6),
   start_date DATE,
   end_date DATE
   create_date DATE
   );

  Create sequence emp_attendance_seq;


insert into emp_attendance (seq_num, employee_id, start_date, end_Date)
   with
   prep (employee_id, start_date, rn, end_date) as (
     select employee_id, access_date
        , row_number()      over (partition by card_num order by access_date)
      , lead(access_date) over (partition by card_num order by access_date)
   from   access_history
 where  location_id in ( select location_id
                     from   locations
                      where  location_type = 'T'
                  )
  )
  select 
    emp_attendance_seq.nextval,
      employee_id,
     start_date,
     nvl(end_date, start_date)
    from prep
   where  mod(rn, 2) = 1;




1  06212020.   06212020  SYSDATE
    21:02:04.     23:52:14

2   06212020.  06212020  SYSDATE
 08:32:35        15:39:05 

3  06212020   06222020.  SYSDATE 
    15:39:05     04:04:35



  --- changes
  -- INSERT records
  -- if end_date is NULL set to start date
    --  Added sequence number to row for unique identification
```

Comment: So, the pairing is simply by card number and location id, then order all the rows (with date >= last start date) ascending by access date, and then pair the first row with the second, third with fourth, etc.? (Since I don't see an IN/OUT flag; perhaps physical sensors don't have that feature.) Is it always guaranteed that an employee leaves from the same location they last entered? At my old co. an employee could enter through one door (one sensor) and leave through a different building (different sensor), is that not possible in your case?

Comment: Also, I assume the last table you show, EMP_ATTENDANCE, is the desired result, right? What is the CREATE_DATE column? How is it populated?

Comment: You are correct on all your points. Card num is the driving force as that is what is being read to allow access and to try and generate attendance I'm just carrying empid along as people are more familiar with that than some card number. Also, there are no designated in or out sensors as they in many places are just mounted on the wall and there are no turnstiles to force direction like in a subway station. As for creat date I was thinking it may come in handy to see when the record is created. I can drop the column at a later date if not needed

Comment: Lastly it doesn't have to be paired by location I'd as people can clock in from the front entrance and leave from the back, east, west, north, south. The key is location type = T for time & attendance or A for access to a secure spot in one if the buildings. For my purpose I need to ignore the 'A' as those records are stored in the access history table too.

Comment: OK, so the "pairing" is really only by employee, and date/time sequence, ignoring the 'A' location type. Partition by employee, not by employee and location. Then, the obvious question: what happens when employees forget to punch the card (either entering or leaving)? Or is that never possible? (Or do we just assume it is never possible and work under that assumption?)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the "main query" which will return the pairings, given the inputs and your problem description. This can be turned into a view (perhaps a materialized view, depending on your needs), or it can be used for a `MERGE` statement.

Warning about storing this data in a table though (like your `EMP_ATTENDANCE`, maintained with `MERGE` statements or in other ways): If you ever need to correct data in the input table (for example a card wasn't read correctly by a sensor, and you must either delete a row or insert a row five days after the fact), all the pairings from that date/time forward, for all employees involved, will be completely messed up. A "start date" may now become an "end date" and vice versa; it is not even clear how a `MERGE` statement would be written to account for such situations.

Anyway, here's the "main query". The main work is in the subquery; it uses two analytic functions, but they use the same `partition by` and `order by` criteria, so the work is actually only done once. The outer query simply applies a filter to keep only every other row. This should be more efficient than creating just the row number (not the `LEAD` function) and applying `PIVOT`. This is because `PIVOT` is an expensive operation (a "sort"), and it would still require the use of an analytic function first anyway. If we must compute `ROW_NUMBER`, we get `LEAD` essentially for free, as I just explained.

```
with
  prep (employee_id, start_date, rn, end_date) as (
    select employee_id, access_date
         , row_number()      over (partition by card_num order by access_date)
         , lead(access_date) over (partition by card_num order by access_date)
    from   access_history
    where  location_id in ( select location_id 
                            from   locations 
                            where  location_type = 'T'
                          )
  )
select employee_id, start_date, end_date
from   prep
where  mod(rn, 2) = 1
;

EMPLOYEE_ID START_DATE          END_DATE           
----------- ------------------- -------------------
          1 2020-06-21 21:02:04 2020-06-21 23:52:14
          2 2020-06-21 08:32:35 2020-06-21 15:39:05
          3 2020-06-21 15:39:05 2020-06-22 04:04:35
```

Comment: Looks great thanks. I will need to test. If you noticed in the employees table I have a column last_start_date if I save that value for each employee the next run should find records greater than that value and will not start from the beginning, therefore the data saved in emp_attendance should keep its integrity. Is that a correct o assumption? At some point I may be deleting old history records once they are paired. Is my assessment correct and could I easily save the last_start_date in query above and INSERT the data into emp_attendance

Comment: With incremental updates, an issue will be that you must "remember" not only what the last date was, but also whether the last row (for each id) was a start date or an end date. Once you figure that out, the query can be modified slightly to accommodate cases where the "first row" is an end date, not a start date. But, consider also the question I asked earlier, about making corrections to "older" data. How will those be reflected in your new table? It seems to me that this best be a view (materialized, if needed).

Comment: As I will always have a paired record or a record with a start date and a null end date, I was thinking for the latter I can make the end date the same as the start date, resulting with a record with zero time, which is like a no-op when calculating sum of worked time. Hopefully that could be done with a NVL command in the query you wrote. As for the max start DATETIME that should be available as the query is traversing the data. I just need to figure out the syntax to do the update. At some point this table will be big and data will have to be deleted or archived. I always see that.

Comment: Hope I explained myself well. Do my ideas make sense now or do they seemed flawed. Fyi, I believe after gathering attendance records my company will be implementing guard tour, where a guard makes his rounds, which will add even more data to the access_history table. Who knows what other ideas Corp will want to implement. So my solution has to be able to scale

Comment: I added your code and a few little changes to my original post along with comments about the changes. One last question if you don't mind. Could the CTE you added be modified to update a new column in the access_history table to mark the records used to create the pairing. Than on subsequent runs modify the where clause to add AND processed=0. I can easily modify create table command  but I'm unsure where to place the update command AND where proccessed=0. Once that's working I think I'm done. Ince again thanks for your help, expertise and patience